# If a dictionary key contains a certain word, how would I remove it?

Tags: python, dictionary

A simple program about storing rivers and their respective locations in a dictionary. I was wondering how I would go about looping through a dictionary key and looking if the dictionary key (or value) contains a certain word, if the word is present in the key, remove it.

EX: `rivers_dict = {'mississippi river': 'mississippi'}`

How would I remove the word 'river' in the dictionary key 'mississippi river'? I know i can assign something such as: `rivers_dict['mississippi'] = rivers_dict.pop('mississippi river')`. Is there a way to do this in a more modular manner? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to use loop.

Comment: Generally the best approach is to build a new dict, filtering along the way. If it is readable, use a dict-comprehension.

Comment: If you only want to do this once (as shown), then your code is pretty good. There's no way to modify a dictionary key in place -- you have to remove the old item and write a new one. If you want to do this for a whole dictionary, you can either scan through all the items and use code like you've shown, or you could construct a new dictionary based on the one you have (often a better choice).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a `dict` comprehension instead of doing it `inplace` ? *Replacing* the name of the key in a `dict`, you can easily do that by using `dict` comprehension -

```
no_rivers_dict = { key.replace('river', ''):value for key, value in rivers_dict.items() }

print(no_rivers_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'mississippi ': 'mississippi', 'nothing': 'nile'}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: the condition isn't necessary since `key.replace('river', '')` will just return the unchanged string if it isn't present

Comment: Good Point @avigil  - just kept that for the articulation! Anyway, modified ans!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex logic to strip away the part of the key you don't want. The question is how to achieve modular logic.

One suggestion is to copy all values into a new dictionary, then delete the old. If something goes awry in that process, the old one would still be left in its entirety. Upon completion of copy, the old one could be deleted.

```
new_dict = {re.sub((r'river', '', k): v for k, v in rivers_dict.items()}
```

Now this code is not tested, but if you included a replicable example, I could test it to see if it does what I want it to do.

So there is a for loop, that takes each key, value `(k,v)` pair from the old dictionary. It then assigns them into new_dict with the modification on the key using regex logic, specifically re.sub(). That should subtract any substring matching `river`. You need to import the regex module

```
import re
```

You can read more about re.sub here https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

With added try-catch blocks, safeguards can be placed so that the old dictionary is not deleted if it did not copy successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to take out instances of 'river' as a full word, and you also want to remove the corresponding space character, you could combine a dict comprehension and list comprehension like this:

```
rivers_dict = {'mississippi river': 'mississippi'}
rivers_dict = {
    ' '.join(word for word in key.split() if word != 'river'): val
    for key, val in rivers_dict.items()
}
```

If you need to do a lot of them, it could look like this:

```
drop_words = {'river', 'stream', 'brook'}
rivers_dict = {'mississippi river': 'mississippi'}
rivers_dict = {
    ' '.join(word for word in key.split() if word not in drop_words): val
    for key, val in rivers_dict.items()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the enumerate function that will count all the words like looping it as
for index, value in enumerate(dic):